# PHP fopen 'x+' doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron, fopen

I created an application which has an caching script on an Windows/Wamp environment. This script's caching function is only allowed to run once at the same time.

To achieve this I used a 'locking file' with check to see if it exists.

On windows this script continues to work fine. But now it is moved to an Ubuntu environment is doesn't work.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    ignore_user_abort(true);

    $path = 'locked.txt';

    if ($lock = fopen($path,'x+')) {
        fwrite($lock,time());
        fclose($lock);
        sleep(10);
        unlink($path);
    }
?>
```

Error: `fopen(locked.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: `@fopen` is suppressing possible errors which would otherwise indicate what the problem is.

Comment: @apokryfos removed the suppression `@`. But there are no errors. I also edited my post with a simpler piece of code.

Comment: Copy-pasted your code. Works fine on my 14.04 ubuntu. Make sure you've got execute permissions on the directory since you can't delete if you don't.

Comment: I do have errors, sorry. I made a mistake. The error is as follows 'fopen(locked.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied'.

Comment: Your web server does not have permissions to open `locked.txt` file in reand and/or write mode.

Comment: Is this script running via the CLI or web?

Comment: @apokryfos It will be possible to run the script from web (if not already running) but a cron will also run the script every ~5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP documentation (paraphrased a bit):

> x+ Create and open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file. If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. This is equivalent to specifying O_EXCL|O_CREAT flags for the underlying open(2) system call.

From your description you are attempting to use a file as a lock file using the "x+" flag to ensure you're not locking a file already locked.

The problem is that migrating from windows to *NIX systems (like Ubuntu) you will need to familiarise yourself with the difference in the permissions system.

The short story is:

Each file and folder "belongs" to a user.

The user who wants to create a file in a directory needs at least an execute and write permission on that directory.

Having this in mind you need to ensure that the current user has write and execute permissions on the **directory** with the script and to actually execute the script they will also need read permissions on the directory (in addition to read permissions on the script). Ensure that the directory has read-write-execute permissions (flag no. 7) for the user running the script.

If you're running the script via a web interface this user will be `www-data` .

In general `chmod 777 /directory/with/script` should work and grant read-write-execute permissions on the directory for all users.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand the problem and solution. A quick question though: what is the standard permission value (where 777 presumably allows read,write and edit for all, what is the standard value (where apache/php wasn't allowed to write), before i changed it).

Comment: I think the default for a new directory in ubunty is 775 (user and group can read-write-execute) though there's probably a way to change this and it may vary for other unix-like operating systems. Truth is a directory without "execute" permissions can't work as a directory so everyone will be able to read or write needs to also get execute permissions on the directory.